# How to modify price set values on existing membership?

Tags: civimember, price-sets

We are a sailing club. Our members need to pay annually for:
- membership
- parking spot(s) for sailboat : a member can have multiple boats. There are different spots at different prices (outdoor, indoor)
- storage area for surfboard
- locker

I would like some advice how to set this up. Initially, I was thinking about using one membership type ("MemberVVWZ") and one price set, containing the above fields.

I am able now to create a new membership which includes the contributions of the different fields. However, when existing members wants to renew his membership, But instead of *two* boats, he wants to store only *one* boat. This means that I need to modify in fact the values of the price set. Is this possible with CiviCRM?

Or, is it better to make different membership types for the different kinds of contributions (membership "Parking spot," membership "Locker")

Any advice is welcome.